# Using unordered _map to convert integers to characters in C++

Tags: c++

I'm not sure I completely understand hash tables/unordered maps. When I do the following, the code compiles and works properly:

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>

int main() {
    tr1::unordered_map<string, int> base;
    string string1;
    int integer1;

    base["A"] = 0;

    string1 = "A";
    integer1 = base[string1];
    cout << integer1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't compile:

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>

int main() {
    tr1::unordered_map<int, char> base;
    char char1;
    int integer1;

    base[1] = 'A';

    integer1 = 1;
    char1 = base[integer1];
    cout << char1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This yields this error:

> error: no match for call to `'(std::tr1::unordered_map<int, char, std::tr1::hash<int>, s std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, char> >, false>) (int*)'`

Could someone explain to me this problem? I don't think I understand how unordered_map works. I'm compiling with gcc 4.2.1 on an Apple.

Comment: The second snippet with a couple of lines' fix compiles just fine with gcc. See [this](http://ideone.com/yozTA). What compiler are you on?

Comment: @dirkgently I'm using g++ 4.2.1, maybe I should update?

Comment: That is pretty old considering GCC released 4.7 (with a wonderful C++11 support). It could be a bug in the implementation. So, yes, I guess you will need to upgrade. Also, if you're on Apple, this may be a bit behind *actual* GCC 4.2.1!

Comment: @dirkgently I am on an Apple. Is there any problem upgrading past what Apple "supports"?

Comment: I can't really say, I haven't touched Apple in a while. But from what I hear, it should be fairly easy to keep both (the existing and a new one).

Comment: It looks like the error doesn't come from this actual code. Can you make and verify a minimal example that exhibits your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The following compiles and works fine with both Visual C++ 10.0 and MinGW g++ 4.6.1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    using std::unordered_map;
    using std::cout;  using std::endl;

    unordered_map<int, char> base;
    char char1;
    int integer1;

    base[1] = 'A';

    integer1 = 1;
    char1 = base[integer1];
    cout << char1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**TR** is short for “Technical Report”. TR1 was the first technical report, and contained extensions to the standard library. Those extensions have already been adopted in the C++11 standard, and most have already been implemented in e.g. Visual C++ and g++.

So, just use the standard library directly.